# Expressão regular AWK imprimir dentro de colchetes

Tags: regex, awk

olha, dentro do meu arquivo.txt possui o seguinte descrição:

```
Flags: X - disabled, E - established

 0 E name="peer1_cymru" instance=default remote-address=38.xx.xx.xx
     remote-as=65555 tcp-md5-key="WUf4f8" nexthop-choice=default
     multihop=yes route-reflect=no hold-time=3m ttl=default
     in-filter=CYMRU-IN out-filter=CYMRU-OUT address-families=ip,ipv6
     update-source=ether1 default-originate=never remove-private-as=no
     as-override=no passive=no use-bfd=no remote-id=xx.xx.xx.xx
     local-address=xx.xx.xx.xx uptime=3h32m11s prefix-count=90668
     updates-sent=0 updates-received=90668 withdrawn-sent=0
     withdrawn-received=0 remote-hold-time=3h used-hold-time=3m
     used-keepalive-time=1m refresh-capability=yes as4-capability=yes
 state=established
```

Preciso no terminal do linux utilizando o awk que é o que eu conheço para pegar somente o item prefix-count=90668. Precisaria que a saída do comando seja igual: [90668] Como proceder?

Answer (score 4):

Tente usar isso com a input que você recebe:

```
'awk 'match($0, /prefix-count=(.*)/) {
print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
```

**Explicação:**

`'awk 'match($0,` - Começa o awk e inicia a parte de RegEx com o espaço 0 da memória, onde será inserido o input.

`/prefix-count=(.*)/` - Isso delimita que a RegEx capturará qualquer coisa após a sequencia **prefix-count=** até o final da linha.

`print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)` - Isso faz o print com o que a RegEx retorna, do início ao fim do *match*

Comment: obs: Caso o output que você deseja inclua os colchetes na forma RAW da saída, só usar isso:

awk 'match($0, /prefix-count=(.*)/) {
print substr(\[$0\], RSTART, RLENGTH)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar esse comando:

```
awk -F = '/90668$/{print $NF}' arquivo
```

A opção `-F` especifica que "=" é um separador de campos! o awk procura no arquivo pela valor predefinido /90668$/ o caracter `$` (final) server para indicar que esse valor está no final da linha! `print $NF` é para imprimir o último campo ! também poderia ter sido assim!

```
awk -F = '/8$/{print $NF}'
```

Arquivo 90668 que teria o mesmo resultado! no caso dessa questão em si

Comment: Tem como explicar o que esse comando faz?

Comment: a opção -F e para especificar que "=" é um separador de campos!

o awk procura no arquivo pela valor predefinido /90668$/  o caracter "$" (final)
server pra indicar q esse valor esta no final da linha!

print $NF e pra imprimir o último campo !

também poderia ter sido assim!

awk -F = '/8$/{print $NF}' arquivo
90668

q teria o mesmo resultado! no caso dessa questao em si!